# Windows 10 - Find when a remote laptop was last restarted (not rebooted)

Tags: windows-10

How to do you tell when a windows 10 laptop was last **restarted** (rather than shutdown/started)?

Systeminfo is updated with a shutdown/start and a reboot.

System Boot Time:          09/01/2017, 11:42:48

I'll like to be able to check other laptops on the work domain.

Comment: Isn't a shutdown just a "shutdown/started"? Don't think there is a way to differentiate the two.

Comment: Pure guess, but if you can see the entire log, a quick reboot would show previous info from a few seconds/minutes earlier. A shutdown would leave a larger time gap. [Not perfect, as someone might have shut down then immediately booted]

Comment: Thanks for all the comments I'm assuming that a restart is a more 'thorough' reboot in Win 10 than a separate shutdown,
<BR>Last entry before shutdown/restart
13 The operating system is shutting down at system time ‎2017‎-‎01‎-‎16T16:33:49.210956000Z.

1st entry after a start
12 The operating system started at system time ‎2017‎-‎01‎-‎16T20:56:34.491719300Z.

Comment: A restart is indeed more thorough *if* you have Fast Startup enabled - see https://old.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/kssm4m/i_knew_i_wasnt_crazy_fast_startup_is_likely_the/ for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can check in the event viewer of Windows

Within System Logs > System you can search for all occurances of event id: 6006 (This is for when the computer is shutting down).

6005 and 6009 are for the computer starting back up.